How to implement [Authorize] in claim-based using .net Identity
I'm working on ASP.NET core web API.
I have implemented the register method and generated the JWT.
In JWT I have only the name that has userId.
var tokenClaims = new List<Claim>
{
    new(ClaimTypes.Name, userExist.Id),
};



var token = GetToken(tokenClaims);

var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

But I save other claims like Role and other data in the ASPNETUSERCLAIMS table.
var authClaims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new(ClaimTypes.Name, userExist.Id),
        new(CustomClaimTypes.ChannelId, userExist.ChannelId.ToString())
    };

foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
{
    authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
}

await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(userExist, authClaims);

I would like to implement the [Authorize(ClaimType = "Roles", ClaimValues = UserRoles.User]
I have implemented the custom Authenticate method like this
public class ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public string ClaimType { get; set; }
    public string[] ClaimValues { get; set; }

    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var principal = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            return;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClaimType) && ClaimValues != null && ClaimValues.Length > 0)
        {
            var hasRequiredRole = ClaimValues.Any(role => principal.HasClaim(ClaimType, role));

            if (!hasRequiredRole)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult();
                return;
            }
        }

        // User is Authorized, continue with execution
    }
}

But, I have saved the claims in the DB token haven't that.
How to implement this?

You can try to Apply the policy using the Policy property on the [Authorize] attribute to specify the policy name.
for example  registering the policy takes place as part of the Authorization service configuration, typically in the Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RolesOnly", policy =>
                      policy.RequireClaim("EmployeeNumber", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"));
});

Then :
[Authorize(Policy = "RolesOnly")]
public IActionResult VacationBalance()
{
    return View();
}

You can have a look at Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET Core to know more.
